# Why CUDA gives inconsistent results when copying a value from an array whose index is far from the thread index?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, cuda

The following code gives inconsistent results when `offset` exceeds approximately 20500. Although this value may depend on your platform and GPU architecture, I think the problem is reproducible for sufficiently large `offset`.

```
#ifndef __CUDACC__ 
#define __CUDACC__
#endif
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"

#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

constexpr unsigned int N = 100000; // array size
constexpr unsigned int BLOCK_DIM = 256;
constexpr unsigned int GRID_DIM = (N + BLOCK_DIM - 1) / BLOCK_DIM;
constexpr unsigned int offset = 30000; // please set the offset here

__global__ void foo(float* a, float* b) {
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (tid < N) {
        b[tid] *= a[tid];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (tid < 10) {
        b[tid] = b[tid + offset];
    }
}

int main(void) {
    float* a, * b, *resCpu, * dev_a, * dev_b, *resGpu;

    // Allocate on host
    a = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    b = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    resCpu = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);
    resGpu = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * N);

    // Allocate on device
    cudaMalloc(&dev_a, sizeof(float) * N);
    cudaMalloc(&dev_b, sizeof(float) * N);

    // Initialize arrays
    float phase = 0.2f;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = std::sin((float)i);
        b[i] = std::sin((float)i + phase);
    }

    // Replicate GPU algorithm on CPU 
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        resCpu[i] = a[i] * b[i];
    }
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N / 2; j++) {
        resCpu[j] = resCpu[j + offset];
    }

    // Transfer data to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Kernel call
    foo <<< GRID_DIM, BLOCK_DIM >>> (dev_a, dev_b);

    // Copy result to host
    cudaMemcpy(resGpu, dev_b, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Print and compare CPU and GPU results
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("cpu[%d] = %.4f\n", i, resCpu[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("gpu[%d] = %.4f\n", i, resGpu[i]);
    }

    // Free memory 
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(resCpu);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(resGpu);
}
```

I have the following output for `offset = 30000`, which exhibits quite undefined behaviors:

```
cpu[0] = 0.7263
cpu[1] = 0.7926
cpu[2] = 0.0022
cpu[3] = 0.5937
cpu[4] = 0.8918
cpu[5] = 0.0522
cpu[6] = 0.4529
cpu[7] = 0.9590
cpu[8] = 0.1371
cpu[9] = 0.3151

gpu[0] = -0.9048
gpu[1] = -0.8472
gpu[2] = -0.0106
gpu[3] = 0.8357
gpu[4] = 0.9137
gpu[5] = 0.1516
gpu[6] = -0.7498
gpu[7] = -0.9619
gpu[8] = -0.2896
gpu[9] = 0.6489
```

However, when I run it with `offset = 100`, I have the following, which is quite consistent:

```
cpu[0] = 0.1645
cpu[1] = 0.2804
cpu[2] = 0.9900
cpu[3] = 0.2836
cpu[4] = 0.1619
cpu[5] = 0.9696
cpu[6] = 0.4190
cpu[7] = 0.0695
cpu[8] = 0.9110
cpu[9] = 0.5601

gpu[0] = 0.1645
gpu[1] = 0.2804
gpu[2] = 0.9900
gpu[3] = 0.2836
gpu[4] = 0.1619
gpu[5] = 0.9696
gpu[6] = 0.4190
gpu[7] = 0.0695
gpu[8] = 0.9110
gpu[9] = 0.5601
```

Do you have any idea why the GPU starts exhibiting undefined behaviors when offset becomes large? The allocated memory is coalesced, but the kernel fetches a value in global memory that is far from its thread ID. What happens on the hardware level? I don't think there is a race condition as each thread accesses a location that does not interfere with another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In CUDA, the proper mental/programming model is that there is no defined order of thread execution.  Threads do not necessarily run in lockstep, and the order among threads is undefined.  That is, for your example, the thread that has the `tid` of 0 may be the very first thread to run, and it may run to completion before any other thread has begun.  Or the `tid` 0 thread may be the last thread to run, not beginning until all other threads have finished.  Or anything in between, with any level or lack of concurrency between threads.  **No ordering is prescribed by CUDA.**
2. `__syncthreads()` is not a grid-wide or device-wide sync.  It acts as an execution barrier only for [threads in a block](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).  When 2 threads belong to different blocks, `__syncthreads()` imposes no ordering on those 2 threads, relative to each other.

Your code has a race condition.  Specifically by that I mean that the results will vary depending on the order of thread execution.

A simple thought experiment may illustrate, I believe.  Suppose thread (`tid`) 0 runs first, and runs to completion, before thread (`tid`) 30000 (0 + `offset`).   Thread 0 will start by multiplying its `b` value by its `a` value, and then storing that result in `b`.  Then it will take the original, unmodified `b` value corresponding to thread 30000, and add it to its own `b` value.  There is nothing in your code that prevents this ordering of execution.  Thread 0 and thread 30000 belong to different blocks.  Suppose `a` and `b` arrays start out containing all 2 values.  So thread 0 in this scenario produces a final result of 2x2+2 = 6.

Now suppose the case where thread 30000 runs first, and runs to completion, before thread 0.  Thread 30000 takes its `b` value and its `a` value and multiplies them together, and stores the result in `b`.  So the `b` value for thread 30000 now contains 4.  Some time later, thread 0 runs. Thread 0 takes its `b` value (2) and multiplies it by its `a` value (2) and stores the result in `b`.  It then adds the `b` value corresponding to thread 30000 to it.  But this `b` value is now 4, instead of 2, because thread 30000 has already run.  So the final value produced by thread 0 is 2x2+4 = 8.

The results are different, depending on order of execution, and CUDA specifies no order of execution to sort that out for you.  It is your responsibility as a CUDA programmer to sort this out.

If we converted the `__syncthreads()` to a grid-wide or device-wide sync point, then the race condition would be resolved.  All threads would have to update their `b` value with the product of `a`, before any thread was then allowed to consume `b` further for the addition.

There are several possible methods for grid-wide sync in CUDA, the first/original method was the kernel launch boundary.  Therefore if you convert the two portions of your `foo` kernel into 2 separate kernel calls, the race condition is resolved and the results should be consistent, both run-to-run, across different device architectures, and with the CPU results.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. There is indeed a race condition. I will delve into the grid-wide sync method. Thank you very much for your help.